# How to get time using Moment JS

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I've two javascript variables: `startDate` and `endDate`. I want to store the current time(unix timestamp in ms) to `endDate` and timestamp of 24 hours before in `startDate`. I'll use this two variables to query the records for last 1 day. How can I do that using **moment JS**?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you looked at the website yet? It's full of examples - http://momentjs.com/ I think what you are trying to do is as simple as

```
var startDate = moment(endDate).subtract(1, 'days');
```

Following your question more literally, you can do this:

```
var endDate = moment(); //the current time
```

Or, you can just ignore the endDate part of this problem and go straight to startDate with

```
var startDate = moment().subtract(1, 'days'); //one day before the current time
```

Finally, if you need to format it a certain way, you can apply a formatting rule such as:

```
moment().subtract(1,'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss a')
```

Use format without an argument and it gives you ISO 8601 format

```
moment().subtract(1,'days').format() //eg: "2015-04-04T01:53:26-05:00"
```

Comment: actually I've figured a workaround


`var startdate = moment.utc(moment().subtract(1, 'days').format("MM/DD/YYYY"), "MM/DD/YYYY").valueOf(); // to unix time stamp in ms`

        `var enddate = moment.utc(moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY"), "MM/DD/YYYY").add('d', 1).subtract('s', 1).valueOf(); // to unix time stamp in ms`

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me although I have never found it in the docs. Should have been published but it works.

Try:

```
moment(currentTime).format("hh:mm"));or 
var currentTime = moment();
    console.log("CURRENT TIME: " + moment(currentTime).format("hh:mm"));
```

Answer (score 13):

For those who are looking for a way to get timestamp, just do it:

> moment().[valueOf](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)()

Answer (score 10):

I think what you are looking for is something like

```
moment(endDate).unix()
```

which returns something like:
1435161240

You can even calculate the time from now using

```
moment(endDate).fromNow()
```

which returns something like:
"2 days ago"

Answer (score 10):

You can directly call function **momentInstance.valueOf()**, it will return numeric value of time similar to **date.getTime()** in native java script.

Comment: for clarification: `moment().valueOf()` outputs exactly the same as `new Date().getTime()`